# asp.net C# and Linq issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a DropDown list I am trying to pupulate from a DataTable.  Each row contains the short date, and the second column contains the month name followed by the year.

Something like this:

```
6/11/2011      June 2011
7/11/2011      July 2011
```

I am trying to throw the second column into a drop down list.

```
dateListDropDown.DataSource = DateList.Rows.Select(x=> x[1].ToString());
dateListDropDown.DataBind();
```

But I don't think I have the Linq correct.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dateListDropDown.DataSource = DateList.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[1].ToString());
dateListDropDown.DataBind();
```

OR

```
dateListDropDown.DataSource = (from a in DateList.AsEnumerable()
                                         select a).ToList();
dateListDropDown.DataTextField = "YourSecondColumnName";
dateListDropDown.DataBind();
```

Comment: First one worked as mentioned in the comment above.  But since I have to wait to answer it, you can have it. :)

Answer (score 0):

try following (assuming data is not null)

```
 var list = new List<string>();

 foreach(var row in DateList.Rows)
   list.Add(row[1] as string);

 dateListDropDown.DataSource = list;
```

As you have mentioned in comments, the error is coming as DataRowCollection does not implement IEnumerable.

Comment: Yeah I have a check in place so the code will never reach here if the data is null.

Comment: System.Data.DataRowCollection does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' acceptiong a first argument of type 'system.data.datarowcollection' could be found.  I am referenceing using System.Linq;

Comment: OK, seems like DataRowCollection does not implement IEnumerable. Only option is to use simple for loop.

Comment: Got an answer from another source.  This fixed it right up. `dateListDropDown.DataSource = DateList.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[1].ToString());`